# Is it good practice to check UI elements' modifications with unit tests using Jest?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I'm new to TDD and learning to use `Jest` with `JavaScript`

What I understood is one of the good practices is to unit test functions which does some business logic, but I'm not sure if it's good to test UI changes e.g. a function adding / deleting / modifying UI element with unit test ?

Comment: I would use integration tools, or other testing, rather than unit testing.  The UI can be tested more in an integration test, such that a button clicks opens a panel etc.  Storybook, Cypress, etc. are good options there.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, can you please share any open source GH projects which I can refer to as a beginner to JS Unit Testing with Jest ?